# What is $\frac{2x}{1-x^2}$ when $x=\sqrt{\frac{1-\cos\theta}{1+\cos\theta}}$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

If

$$x=\sqrt{\frac{1-\cos\theta}{1+\cos\theta}}$$

Find

$$\frac{2x}{1-x^2}$$

I got till here by simplification by taking the previous value of x, ie,
$$x={\frac{\sqrt{1-\cos\theta}}{1+\cos\theta}}$$
$$\frac{2\tan\theta\sqrt{1+\cos\theta}}{\cos\theta+3}$$

Comment: Are you sure the definition of $x$ is not the following? $$x=\sqrt{\frac{1-\cos\theta}{1+\cos\theta}}$$
It would be so much simpler with this...

Comment: I don't get the question - are we trying to do anything in particular apart from substituting x and simplifying??

Comment: @surelyourejoking No, but simplification is not easy with $x$ defined as is. However, if it's the definition in my comment, it's almost trivial.

Comment: Also suspect the question should be like Jean-Claude Arbaut defined, so you can play around with double/half angle formula of cos and tan

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut I am not particularly sure. The answer should be tanΘ. Maybe I should try check with the value of x you gave.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$$x=\sqrt{\frac{1-\cos\theta}{1+\cos\theta}}$$

But $\cos2a=2\cos^2a-1=1-2\sin^2a$, so

$$1-\cos\theta=2\sin^2 \frac{\theta}{2}$$
$$1+\cos\theta=2\cos^2 \frac{\theta}{2}$$

Hence

$$x=\left|\tan \frac{\theta}2\right|$$

Therefore

$$\frac{2x}{1-x^2}=\frac{2\left|\tan\frac{\theta}2\right|}{1-\tan^2\frac{\theta}2}=\frac{\left|2\sin\frac{\theta}2\cos\frac{\theta}2\right|}{\cos^2\frac{\theta}2-\sin^2\frac{\theta}2}=\frac{|\sin\theta|}{\cos\theta}$$

Notice that the answer is not $\tan\theta$, when $\sin\theta<0$, that is for

$$\theta \in \bigcup_{k\in\Bbb Z} ](2k-1)\pi,2k\pi[$$

Or, if we remove also the values of $\theta$ for which $\cos\theta=0$,
$$\theta \in \bigcup_{k\in\Bbb Z} ]-\pi+2k\pi,-\pi/2+2k\pi[\;\cup\;]-\pi/2+2k\pi,2k\pi[$$

Comment: yea I too got the same answer with your value of x. Thank you @Jean

Comment: please edit the question. Thank you for your answer. I too got tan(-) with your value.

Comment: @LeMauvaisGenie I edited the answer, actually you must be very careful with sign, if you make no assumption on $\theta$.

Answer (score 0):

$$x=\sqrt\frac{1-cos(\theta)}{1+cos(\theta)}.$$ Suppose to the given equation, let it be defined such that $$y = \frac{2x}{1-x^2}$$ Just substitute x in the equation y will result $$ 1-x^2 = 1 - \frac{1-cos(\theta)}{1+cos(\theta)} \implies \frac{2 cos(\theta)}{1+cos(\theta)}.$$ similarly $$x=\sqrt\frac{1-cos(\theta)}{1+cos(\theta)} * \sqrt\frac{1+cos(\theta)}{1+cos(\theta)} \implies \sqrt\frac{sin^2(\theta)}{(1+cos(\theta))^2} $$ $$ x = \frac{sin(\theta)}{1+cos(\theta)}$$ Equation y  can be rewritten as $$y = \frac{2 sin(\theta)/(1+cos(\theta))}{2cos(\theta)/(1+cos(\theta)} $$ Hence, $$ \frac{2x}{1-x^2} = tan(\theta)$$

Comment: Notice $\sqrt{x^2}=|x|$, so $\neq x$ if $x<0$.